# In early Western democracies what percentage of men were eligible to vote?

Tags: voting

From what I've seen in the below sources, it appears that a large number of men didn't vote during the early times. May I know if this is true to most places as well? Why was this the case and when did most men get their right to vote?

[Source 1](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/pathways/citizenship/struggle_democracy/getting_vote.htm)

In early-19th-century Britain, very few people had the right to vote. A survey conducted in 1780 revealed that the electorate in England and Wales consisted of just 214,000 people - less than 3% of the total population of approximately 8 million. In Scotland the electorate was even smaller: in 1831 a mere 4,500 men, out of a population of more than 2.6 million people, were entitled to vote in parliamentary elections.

[Source 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20160706144856/http://www.archives.gov/exhibits/charters/charters_of_freedom_13.html)

America: At the time of the first Presidential election in 1789, only 6 percent of the population–white, male property owners–was eligible to vote.

[Source 3](https://www.sfu.ca/~aheard/elections/historical-turnout.html)

Between 1867 and 1874 in Canada only <12% of the population eligible to vote

Comment: Which democracies are you most interested in? Tracing the evolution of voting in every western democracy is verging on too broad.

Comment: Britain and its colonies like America and Canada. (don't mind if I get info on just those 3)

Comment: Distinguishing between where property ownership was a precondition and general (male) suffrage would be appropriate, since the first is the main reason for the lower percentage.

Comment: This is a really interesting question, with good preliminary research.  What was the definition of suffrage in early Western democracies?  (I know that in Colonial America, I would have been ineligible to vote  because my father is still alive, and I don't own land.  )  [Suffrage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffrage) might be a good place to start. Might be interesting to compare the British concept of Democracy with other democratic populations.  On the other hand, at some point this becomes a book. An interesting book, but longer than an H:SE answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen some spotty numbers for this. One method I've seen used to measure how Liberal (in the 18th century sense) a Democracy was by its voting franchise %. I don't know if anyone's compiled it exhaustively for all of Europe for all of time though.

Comment: (Of course that isn't a perfect measure, because the bodies those voters elected held varying amounts of power in various places and times as well)

Comment: I'm a little a confused...in a comment you said you're interested in "Britain and its colonies like America and Canada", but you've already done some research there and found some data (and credit to you for that), so what is left exactly that you want?

Comment: @LarsBosteen It's because in Wikipedia I found this : "Due to the greater availability of land, the right to vote was more widespread in the colonies where by one estimate around 60 percent of adult white males could vote."..... So I was really confused with the numbers.

Comment: So it seems you are looking for an explanation for the apparent discrepancy in the colonies numbers? If that is the case, I would suggest you edit that into the question for clarity.

Comment: Too many variables in this question to get a good answer, primarily **when** and **where** are you interested in?

Comment: The quote on Wikipedia about 60% of adult males being able to vote has no citation, and doesn't pass the smell test given the high % of non-propertied men in the early 18th century such as indentured servants and enslaved people.

Comment: Does Ancient Greece count? It is certainly "early," I believe it's normally considered part of the "West" (e.g. often described as the birthplace of Western philosophy), and IIRC they actually invented democracy.

Comment: While this is a very hard question to answer, it seems that -- in the absence of an answer -- many people fill in whatever suits them.  I've seen wild amounts of variance in theories of "who was allowed to vote where and when" depending largely on goals of the speaker.  Seemingly, even a high-tolerance estimation would be better than nothing.